# Jackson ignore subtype property when deserialize

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm using a subType property in Jackson, and I want to using this property when deserializing json.

```
package com.gaosoft.ai.kg.commons.sphinx.strategy;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSubTypes;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;
import com.sankuai.ai.kg.commons.sphinx.model.FAQRecord;
import com.sankuai.ai.kg.commons.sphinx.model.FAQRequest;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        property = "strategyType"
)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = StrategyEmpty.class, name = "empty"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = StrategyNormal.class, name = "normal"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = StrategyDummy.class, name = "dummy")
}
)
public abstract class Strategy implements Serializable {

    private String strategyName;
    private String strategyType;
    private Map<String, Object> args = new HashMap<>();

    public String getStrategyType() {
        return strategyType;
    }

    public void setStrategyType(String strategyType) {
        this.strategyType = strategyType;
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getArgs() {
        return args;
    }

    public void setArgs(Map<String, Object> args) {
        this.args = args;
    }

    public String getStrategyName() {
        return strategyName;
    }

    public void setStrategyName(String strategyName) {
        this.strategyName = strategyName;
    }

    public abstract void init(BeanFactory beanFactory);

    public abstract List<FAQRecord> fetchFAQ(FAQRequest request);
}
```

Like my code says, there are 3 subtype of abstract class Strategy, and I want to retain the subclass type name in strategyType property.
Is there a way to fill strategyType when using jackson in this way?

(Sorry about my poor English)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're asking for is the [`@JsonTypeInfo#visible`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.4/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonTypeInfo.html#visible()) property:

> Note on visibility of type identifier: by default, deserialization (use during reading of JSON) of type identifier is completely handled by Jackson, and is not passed to deserializers. However, **if so desired, it is possible to define property visible = true in which case property will be passed as-is to deserializers (and set via setter or field)** on deserialization.

So in your example,

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
    use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
    property = "strategyType",
    visible = true
)
```

That said, this seems like a design smell.  Is it truly valid that you can set a `StrategyEmpty`'s `strategyType` to `dummy`?  If not, and `StrategyEmpty` should always have a `strategyType` of `empty`, then why not just have an abstract `getStrategyType()` that each subclass implements with a hardcoded value?

Comment: I have thought of that. But the annotation already has this information. Should I do this, the information of subclass is duplicated. Which is also a bad smell :) (Do I write this correctly? I'm not a English-native speaker)

Comment: @Gao: I get what you're saying.  In this case I would say that duplicating the type literals in a getter is a lesser evil than allowing other users of the glass to set the type incorrectly.  You could also use the constructor and `@JsonCreator` to at least inject it into a final field and avoid the setter.  But still, it gives the appearance of supporting a wide range of values when truly each subclass has a static value for that property.